# How to check if FTP server is alive?

Tags: java, android, ftp, ftp-client

I need to check if a FTP server is alive, is this server:

```
ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/upload/
```

I tried with this code:

```
            FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
            try {
                ftp.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                ftp.setDefaultTimeout(5000);
                ftp.setDataTimeout(5000);
                ftp.connect(urlString);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } finally {
                ftp.disconnect();
            }
```

The problem is that is returning this exception:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/upload/": No address associated with hostname

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What happens if the `urlString` is just `speedtest.tele2.net`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `connect` method takes a hostname, not a URL.

The `ftp://` part is useless; this is an FTP client, it can't do anything else.

The `/upload` part is also useless; it can't go to that path until after connecting. Hence, taking a URL just doesn't make sense, so the API is properly the designed.

Call `.connect("speedtest.tele2.net")`.

Comment: thank you, it seems to work, but the problem is sometimes it's taking a loooooooot of time to start the upload of the file i need to upload, and i don't know why. The connect is very fast, but when I try to start the upload, it takes minutes until start. THis function was to check if the server was not ok, but doesn't work to know if the server upload will start or not. Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: the URL is ended with "/". This is the correct url: ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/upload/   are you sure that upload must be removed when connecting for testing purposes?